# Can the Windows Imaging Component return a human-readable format name?

Tags: windows, winapi, wic

I'm using `IWICImagingFactory::CreateDecoderFromFilename` to load images using the Windows Imaging Component (WIC). It returns an `IWICBitmapDecoder` that I can use to get the actual image data.

Is it also possible to get a human-readable string of the image loaded from WIC? E.g. something like "JPEG", "PNG", "GIF" etc.? I know I can use `IWICBitmapDecoder::GetContainerFormat` to get the container format but it returns a `GUID` instead of a human-readable string. So for the GIF format, I'm getting `GUID_ContainerFormatGif` which is not exactly human-readable...

Comment: Where have you seen the WIC human readable string?

Comment: I haven't seen it. That's why I'm asking if it's possible at all.

Comment: You might be able to find the file extension. I doubt it will be able to provide "Portable Network Graphics".

Comment: @HansPassant: But can't WIC be extended using third-party decoders? In that case just comparing the Microsoft built-in GUIDs wouldn't be sufficient.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Thanks, I can confirm that this does the trick! You should post this as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an [IWICBitmapDecoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmapdecoder) reference, you can call the [IWICBitmapDecoder::GetDecoderInfo method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapdecoder-getdecoderinfo). It will get you an [IWICBitmapDecoderInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwicbitmapdecoderinfo) reference ("Exposes methods that provide information about a decoder.").

From that reference (which derives from the [IWICComponentInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nn-wincodec-iwiccomponentinfo) interface), you can call the [IWICComponentInfo::GetFriendlyName method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwiccomponentinfo-getfriendlyname) which will get you "GIF Decoder" in the GIF decoder (GUID_ContainerFormatGif) case.

This [WicNetExplorer](https://github.com/smourier/WicNet/tree/main/WicNetExplorer) open source (.NET C# P/Invoke interop) tool I wrote can display every WIC Component information:

[image]